# Memory problems with xargs and grep and pattern from file

Tags: bash, memory, grep, find, xargs

Within a makefile I run the following command

```
find SOURCE_DIR -name '*.gz' | xargs -P4 -L1 bash -c 'zcat $$1 | grep -F -f <(zcat patternfile.csv.gz) | gzip > TARGET_DIR/$${1##*/}' -
```

`patternfile.csv.gz` contains 2M entries with an unzipped file size of 100MB, each file in `SOURCE_DIR` has a zipped file size of ~20MB.

However, each `xargs` process consumes more than 6GB of RAM. Does this make sense or do I miss something here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that `bash` construct is not operating as you think it is. Change `xargs` to `xargs -t` and change `bash` to `bash -x` to verify that the commands you are running are what you expect. In particular, the `$$1` constructs are doing something I don't think is what you expect...

Comment: I just learned that automata are not linear in memory, was not aware of this.